# How can I reach nested attributes inside an object

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow object detector code but this is not exclusively a tensorflow question. I have made a function to save the most useful parameters to a text file. I am using the code:

```
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
```

to get the actual `config` object. `config` itself is `dict` but the values it contains are all tensorflow specific objects.

```
model_config = configs['model']
type(model_config)
```

> object_detection.protos.model_pb2.DetectionModel

```
train_config = configs['train_config']
type(train_config)
```

> object_detection.protos.train_pb2.TrainConfig

Each of these object contains other tensorflow class objects which I can access through `getattr` function like:

```
type(getattr(train_config.optimizer, 'rms_prop_optimizer'))
```

> object_detection.protos.optimizer_pb2.RMSPropOptimizer

Since I can see the various parameters in the actual text config file I can use a chain of these `getattr` to get to the actual value I am interested in. The problem is that it gets really long (and ugly I would say) and it does not feel the right way to do it. For example to get the actual learning rate from this [sample config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config#L90) I would have to use:

```
getattr(getattr(getattr(getattr(train_config.optimizer, 'momentum_optimizer'), 'learning_rate'), 'manual_step_learning_rate'), 'initial_learning_rate')
```

> 0.0003000000142492354

ok there are some rounding errors here but that's not the point here.

I would like to mention that using the higher level `item in object` does not seem to work for these objects.

I was wondering if there was any way to get that value is a prettier way? A way less error prone and anyway applicable even without the knowing the actual text configuration file.

Strictly speaking this is not a tensorflow question since the `getattr` approach could be applied to any object having attributes but if a tensorflow solution exist I am open to it.

Comment: Try using the 'dir()' function on your object. It will show you what you can call. If it is a dictionary all the way down you can keep using key value pairs.

Comment: Also, dot notion all the way down might work. (Sorry on mobile can't test it)

Comment: Both `dir()` and dot does not seem to do the job. They get some attributes but not the ones I want (not sure why is that).